# Need help try to make this xsl style sheet to feed in to one line following next line right behind

Tags: java, xslt

Marquee xsl style sheet in sharepoint pulling from Announcements. Want all the announcement in one roll not 3 or four rolls.can this be done?

Here the codeany help would work.

```
<xsl:template name="MarqueeTitleOnly" 
              match="Row[@Style='MarqueeTitleOnly']" 
              mode="itemstyle">

<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
      <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

<div class="item link-item">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
  <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
    <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <div style="color: #77504; font-size: 1pt;">
          <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <div style="color: #77504; font-size: 18pt;">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
        </div >
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
     <div style="color:#77504 ; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15pt;">    
      <marquee direction="left" style="border:; background: ;">
        <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle" />

      </marquee >
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add small input xml and expected output.

Comment: Is that not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411168/xsl-marqueetitleonly-in-one-line?